# does explode get executed more than once in a foreach?

Tags: php

```
$array='hello hello2';
foreach(explode(' ',$array) as $v)
 echo $v;
```

How many times does explode get executed?

And is it better that to use another var like:

```
   $exploded = explode(...);
   foreach($exploded as $v)
      ...
```

?

Comment: To whoever added the 'close' vote to this, I think it's actually a very good question..! I'd be interested to know why you disagree.

Comment: I think that's documented on the foreach page which says it's working on a copy of the `Traversable` (Array, Iterator, ...) value, see http://php.net/foreach.

Comment: @nickf: if someone voted to close i think it's because maybe there is a similar question of this somwhere, but it's hard to find :D (I remember somewhere there is )

Comment: @nickf i closevoted this because i dont see in what situation knowing this would be useful and because the manual already states the obvious.

Comment: @Gordon -- it's very useful knowledge! It's good to know that it doesn't re-evaluate on each iteration like `for ($i = 0; $i < count(explode('...')); ++$i) { }`

Comment: @nickf how is that useful? in what situation? you cant even micro-optimize with that knowledge. And it's general reference material anyway. Easy to lookup in the manual.

Comment: @Gordon that's **not** a micro-optimisation! Maybe in a case where the evaluation is simple and results in only a couple of items to iterate over it wouldn't be a big deal, but if the action is more significant (eg: reading and splitting a large file), then it's very significant. Also, just because something is available in the manual, that doesn't mean it should be excluded from this site.

Comment: @nickf if, when, maybe. I have no interest discussing this. Feel free to cast reopen vote when this gets closed. IMO, its too localized and [general reference](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/).

Comment: Nice real life example: http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/163-mysqli_result-iterations.html

Comment: Unbelievable that this got closed... Useful information and almost exactly what I was looking for (i was looking for inside a 'for' loop rather than 'foreach').  Anything that explains the inner workings of code computation is useful for those who want to know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It only gets executed once. `foreach` will operate on a copy of the return value of `explode` (array or false).

`foreach` is a language construct which expects `$array as $key => $value`. `$array` can be any expression which evaluates to an array, and `explode` is such a function. The expression is evaluated only once, and then foreach operates on the result of the expression.

This is different with a regular `for` loop for instance. A `for` loop takes three expressions. Both the second and third expression are evaluated for each iteration of the loop.

So with a for loop there *could be* a difference (leaving optimization and the O(1)-performance of `count` aside) between these two statements:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) { … }
// vs.
for($i = 0, $c = count($array); $i < $c; ++$i) { … }
```

Comment: Note though that "copy" here means "soft copy", i.e. nothing is copied actually.

Comment: @NikiC: foreach is read-only per default, so it does not need to really copy the memory area, I know. That edit wasn't mine …

Comment: @knittl, there is a small typo in the last `for` loop: $c in the initialization vs. $l in the test.

Comment: @manatwork: Thanks! I usually use `$l` (length-method/function in most programming languages), but that didn't make any sense with count ;)

Answer (score 1):

`explode` will be called only once and will provide the returned array to `foreach` for iteration.

If it is called only once with `foreach`, you may don't want to go with another variable.

But if your explode failed and returns false in any case, foreach will produce a warning so having in another variable give you more control over those warnings and error handling.

Comment: though you can handle it anyway. `if ($array)` will be as good as `if ($exploded)` for this

Answer (score 1):

It only gets executed once. [`foreach`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/foreach) will operate on a copy of the return value of [`explode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/explode).

As the expression containing `explode` will be evaluated once (it's not inside the loop), `explode` will only run once.

But as the return value can be an `array` or `FALSE` and `foreach` does operate only on types that are [`Array`](http://php.net/array) or [`Object`](http://php.net/object), it won't work for `FALSE` which should make it necessary to check the result first before executing the `foreach` which needs the variable, if you want to execute `explode` only once:

```
$array='hello hello2';

if (FALSE === $exploded = explode(' ',$array))
{
    throw new RuntimeException('Explode failed.');
}

foreach ($exploded as $v)
{
   echo $v;
}
```

With this example, for the `foreach` part, `$exploded` is only evaluated once as well.

See as well: [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php).

Comment: `foreach` does **not** only operate on types that implement the `Traversable` interface.

Comment: But on all types that *are* Traverseable (I considered `Array` of such), edited the answer to make that more visible.

Comment: Still, `foreach` will operate on items that don't implement `Traversable` and are not arrays.  If you intend to use the word *traversable* rather than meaning the interface of the same name, best just to remove the link to the interface documentation.

Comment: But I love [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) so much! Damn.

Comment: Any object (visible properties are iterated).

Answer (score 0):

Only one time `explode` will be executed, feel free to use the first one.

Answer (score -4):

second one will make your code more readable and give you ability to output resulting array contents for the debugging purposes.

Comment: More readable? The only thing it does, is to pollute the variable scope with variables you don't need …

Comment: yes, more readable. stacking multiple operators in one line always makes less readable code. and this "pollution" will be sweeped down in a matter of milliseconds anyway. Not to mention that variable scope to pollute is a matter of choice. you can pollute a local method's variable as well

Comment: I think it's more readable too.

Comment: using a variable called `$exploded` does not add anything which `explode()` already does anyway. Scope pollution has nothing to do with runtime, but with the number of available variables (autocompletion, unintended modification of a variable in multiple places, etc.)

Comment: unintended modification of a variable should be solved by *variable initialization*, dude.